# Best way to store <Integer, Integer> KVP in Redis for lookup by both Key and Value

Tags: redis, jedis, key-value-store

I want to store mappings for my own internal Integer IDs and an external systems IDs. For example, I may have the following data:

```
MySystemInteger: 3, ExternalSystemInteger: 5
MySystemInteger: 8, ExternalSystemInteger: 1
MySystemInteger: 4, ExternalSystemInteger: 2
```

I want to be able to get MySystemInteger for a particular ExternalSystemInteger value, and also get an ExternalSystemInteger for a particular MySystemInteger value.

I have done a bit of research, and although the KEYS function of redis would enable me to search values in a keyspace for a particular value, KEYS traverses the entire keyspace to find matches. As Redis is single threaded, access to all databases will be blocked while this process is in operation.

Is there a good way to do this? Or will I have to store two datasets? One where MySystemInteger is the Key and one where ExternalSystemInteger is the key? Thanks

Comment: Your proposed solution of indexing two ways will work if total number of such relations are small, you may consider using hset if such relations are in millions they are very efficient look for hset optimization there are many topics around. A better solution can be proposed if you share more information.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `KEYS` in production is risky and as it mention on [redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys), it may ruin. You may use Hashes for this case;

- `hset pair my:1 ext:7`
- `hset pair ext:7 my:1`
- `hget pair ext:7` returns `my:1`
- `hget pair my:1` returns `ext:7`

if you want you may use `hmset` while setting those two hash fields. Storing them in a different hash is also another option.